# Memory management (leaks?) in Angular and RxJS

Tags: angular, memory, memory-leaks, rxjs

I was trying to reason about lifespan of a subscriber in RxJS. That is, we all know that we need to unsubscribe from an observable, right? But the question is: why?

I am developing a large Angular-based application, so I can't really share my code, but I'll try to give you the context of my thinking experiment. Let's say that we have a following component:

```
class Comp extends Component {
    public o$;
    constructor(private store$: Store) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.o$ = this.store$.pipe(select(...), map(...));
        this.o$.subscribe(function() {
            this.whateverFromComponent(); // Let's tie this to component via closure
        });
    }
}
```

So we could write something like `this.o$.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))` but I'm using a native Angular Router, so probably when I change the subpage, the `Comp` class instance is removed and the only reference to `o$` is removed, so the only reference to the callback is removed and we're all done?

But this seems not to be the case: when the component is removed from DOM, and `onDestroy` was called, I'd expect that instance of `comp` is removed too but it's clearly not removed, since otherwise we wouldn't need to unsubscribe from observables.

So I started to think, that Angular creates the instance of component once, and when it's not used references to the component class instance are not removed but kept for further usage. But this also seems not to be the case, since `console.log` put into a constructor is called everytime a component is rendered on the page.

Ok, so at this point I know that a component instance is not deleted from memory when it is removed from DOM, since the subscription is called anyways. And the component instance is created everytime it's put into DOM. Waaaat?

I've run DevTools and take a snapshot of memory and filtered my a component class name. And indeed, it seems that everytime component is rendered on a page, a new instance is created. So I've ended up with n refs to component even though only one was needed.

I started to dig around and the obsolete component instances are referenced from some subscription, that seems to come from Angular Router.

Could you please help me figuring out when (if ever) is an instance of Component class removed from memory? And why the subscription persists?

Comment: _"we need to unsubscribe from an observable, right?"_ It depends. How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Well, there's plenty of articles in the Internet telling you to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 1):

As long as a stream is active it obviously needs a reference to all subscriptions. Otherwise it could not emit values to the subscribers. When a stream is completed, however, that's no longer the case.

In your example `store$` will (most likely) never complete, therefore you need to unsubscribe. Otherwise the subscription as well as the stream will remain alive (although the name `store$` implies that this particular stream will probably live as long as the application anyway).

When a component instance is removed from memory depends on the garbage collector and whether or not some code still holds a reference to the instance.

Comment: But when I change the page - and hence the smart component - I should free the reference and underlying memory to it and quite a lot of other components. It should eventually be cleaned altogether with the observable and subscriptions but it's not the case

Comment: @TeoTN `store$` is not part of the component and as long as it lives the subscription lives (provided the stream is not  done). Objects will only be removed from memory during garbage collection. If you still have doubts that I suggest you provide more details, e.g. a screenshot from devtools where we can see the component instance and the references.

Comment: But the pipe creates a new observable that is a part of the component, isn't it?